# NetBeans is not debugging correctly after I copy sources

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, netbeans6.8

Dunno why this happens... Ok here is the situation: I have a nb project on my laptop. I have the same project on my desktop. I copy the sources (not the entire project) on the desktop, overwriting the desktop sources. Everything cleans and builds ok. Then I start the debugger. On the main class I can debug step by step. If it goes into an internal method here is what happens:

```
Listening on 37574
User program running
LineBreakpoint test.java : 45 successfully submitted.
Breakpoint hit at line 45 in class test by thread main.
Thread main stopped at test.java:45.
User program running
Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint baseControllerManager.java : 41, reason: No executable location available at line 41 in class baseClasses.JNW.baseControllerManager.
Invalid LineBreakpoint baseControllerManager.java : 41
Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code.
User program finished
```

As you can see until I'm in static method main it works (line 45) as I jump inside a non static method (that is an override) it comes out with that... I tried to:

- clean and build = no effect
- manually delete build and dist = no effect

What do you suggest?

For the sake of completeness I'm attaching the sources of the main class:

```
import baseClasses.JNW.baseAction;
import baseClasses.JNW.baseContResult;
import baseClasses.JNW.baseController;
import baseClasses.JNW.baseControllerManager;

public class test {

    public static class starter extends baseController {

        public static final String ACTION_START = "ACTION_START";

        @Override
        public baseContResult doAction(baseAction action) {

            if (ACTION_START.equals(action.action)) {
                manager.log("action start...");
                return new baseContResult(RESULT_OK, baseContResult.resultType.RESULT_OK);
            }
            return super.doAction(action);
        }

        @Override
        public void init() {
            super.init();
        }
    }

    public void startMe() {
        baseControllerManager manager;
        try {
            manager = new baseControllerManager();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        starter st = new starter();
        manager.setMainController(st);
        manager.doAction(new baseAction(starter.ACTION_START));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        test te = new test();
        te.startMe();

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried checking your netbeans installation? turn off then on again? or reinstall?

Answer (score 2):

Look in the file `nbproject/project.properties` for the property `javac.debug` and make sure that it's "true". If it is, grep for that property elsewhere in the nbproject directory and any local ant settings.

On a semi-related note: when I'm creating a project in NetBeans, even if the sources already exist elsewhere, I always create a new "Java Application", and let it populate the project directory as it wants. Then I can move in my sources and update the project, and NetBeans stays happy.

---

Edit after you tried setting `javac.debug`:

Looking at your question again, I see that you *were* able to set a breakpoint on `test.java`, but not able to set one on `baseControllerManager.java`. That indicates to me that you're getting the latter class from a JAR somewhere, not from your project directory.

So the first step is to make sure that you haven't defined a `CLASSPATH` environment variable. This is *never* a good thing to do, regardless of whether you're using an IDE or a manual build.

Next step is to look at the libraries that you've specified for the NetBeans project. You can use `grep` on a JARfile; the file directory is in plaintext. It should be sufficient to look for the unqualified classname.

And the final thing is to verify that you are indeed compiling the class, by looking for it in the build directory.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, an *uncompilable* error means a symbol could not be resolved.

If you have dependencies on other projects, libraries, or jars, make sure they have built successfully / are present.

Checking "Build Projects on Classpath" (in project properties > Build > Compiling) will often fix this. If you don't have this checked, *you* are responsible for ensuring dependencies are already built.

Comment: Build projects on Classpath is already checked (even if it is on a different location - build > libraries . But I don't think this is the problem as this is a single (and simple project). Everything compiles well, even if I modify something. AND RUNS. The only problem is the debugger. I started this project and everything was working fine (in Eclipse). Then I created a project in NB (ask my boss why) and it started giving me problems like this (I created a project using the Create Project from existing sources option). I redid this a dozen of times, even after reinstalling netbeans, but no way

Comment: Ok, it sounds like the debugger is seeing conflicting information about the class files. Are there any class files under your source directory? The NB approach is to put all the class files in build/classes. However, I see that when I use the "Create Project from existing sources" option it is adding the source directory to the class path. So, it could be there are class files from a pre-NB build that NB doesn't know to remove. Class files where line 41 does not correspond to executable code.

Answer (score 1):

The property was not present in project.properties. So I added it (at a point where there where many javac.* properties...). Then I grepped like this:

```
dario@dario-desktop:~/Scrivania/JNW$ grep -r javac.debug *
nbproject/project.properties:javac.debug=true
nbproject/build-impl.xml:        <property name="javac.debug" value="true"/>
nbproject/build-impl.xml:            <attribute default="${javac.debug}" name="debug"/>
nbproject/build-impl.xml:                <javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
nbproject/private/private.properties:javac.debug=true
nbproject/project.properties~:javac.debug=true
```

In fact it sees my addition on the last line.

I cleaned and rebuilt the project. The debugger is not working again........... I think I'll kick my boss ass until he agrees to use eclipse or he fires me. I'll be unemployed but happy. Apart from joking, @kdgrgory, do you have any more ideas???

Comment: For the future, editing your question is probably the best approach to narrowing down the problem ... I have to scroll back up there anyway, so will attach the next comment there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that if I run clean from project tab it solves the problem.